# Complex Brownian motion and expectation of stopped process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

I know that $$E[e^{i \lambda B_T}] = e^{-  \lambda}, \lambda >0$$ holds for a Complex Brownian motion $B(t)= \mathbf{i} + X_t + \mathbf{i} Y_t$, where $T= \inf\{ t  \geq 0: Y_t = -1 \}$.

I need to use "symmetry" to show that actually $$E[e^{i \lambda B_T}] = e^{-  | \lambda|}, \lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$$

How can I move?

**Edit**

So, let $\lambda <0$.

Then $$E[e^{i (-\lambda)B_T}] = e^{-(-\lambda)} = e^{\lambda}$$ since $-\lambda >0$.

But $E[e^{i (- \lambda) B_T}]=E[e^{i \lambda(-B_T)}] = E[e^{i \lambda B_T}]$

where in the last equality I used the fact that $-(B_t)_t$ has the same distribution as $(B_t)_t$.

All in all $$E[e^{i \lambda B_T}]= e^{\lambda}, \qquad \lambda <0$$

So we can conclude $E[e^{i \lambda B_t}] = e^{- |\lambda|}, \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a brownian motion then so is $(-B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. This is the kind of symmetry that is meant.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks. I edited my answer, please let me know if it's right now!

Comment: Yep, looks good. You should go ahead and post that as answer to the question!